# When does a Q_Property notification signal get called?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In this:

`Q_PROPERTY(QString datastring READ showdata() NOTIFY datastringChanged)`

Is the `datastringChanged` signal for the purposes of emitting a signal when the QML side assigns something new to `datastring` property, or is it for emitting when the C++ side needs to notify the QML side that `showdata()` should be checked again as it has updated information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter. Note that QML has no way to set that property (i.e. it's read only in QML), as it lacks a `WRITE` method.

(And, to nitpick, it's just `READ showdata`, without `()`.)

Comment: if I did make it writable, should QML elements still recognize an `onDatastringChanged` signal if the property is assigned something on the QML side? or would that be a different signal than the one I have specified with NOTIFY?

Comment: Yes, they will. You just need to remember to emit that signal from within your `WRITE` method. Then f.i. all bindings will automatically re-evaluate when the value changes; if you're creating some kind of object creatable in QML, then you can use a plain `onDatastringChanged` handler in QML; if you're just exposing a plain QObject subclass to QML then you can use the `Connections` element, again with the `onDatastringChanged` handler.

Comment: If you define any property in the QML side, it automatically has a signal attached to it that is the same name as the property, prepended with "on". But if you instead define a property on the c++ side, there is no automatic signal attached with any naming convention, right? It will only follow the name of the signal you specify in the Q_PROPERTY macro, right?

Comment: For a property called `property`, the signal is called `propertyChanged`. Then the ordinary syntax for signal handlers applies (`on` + name of the signal, with the first letter capitalized). See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes).